# Handling Arabic Characters in Image URLs for Facebook Link Previews

Tags: facebook, encoding, character-encoding, facebook-opengraph

I have an issue where Facebook and Twitter are not properly rendering link previews for URLs that contain Arabic characters in the image paths.
For instance, a link like
`https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/رابط-الصورة-على-الويب-2024.jpg` 
doesn't display the preview image, whereas links without Arabic characters,
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7I9j.png)

such as `https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/link-web-of-img-2024.jpg` , work fine.

This problem has recently arisen, as it was not an issue in the past. I looking for a solution that would make Facebook and Twitter read the links with their Arabic characters encoded, without having to manually change or encode the URLs for the numerous articles on my website.
Thanks.

I use percentage encoding for Arabic characters in the link. The problem remained the same

Answer (score 0):

I use percentage encoding for Arabic characters in the link with a specific solustion it worked for me

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to improve [mcve]. In particular, share a working code snippet…